# Inputs and Outputs from/to HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get inputs from my HTML process the info in my JS and send a result back to the HTML. In the example the JS calculates the stay of a person in an accommodation. I just need to get their check-in and check-out dates.

```js
var date1 = new Date("7/13/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/15/2010");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Select your Check-in date please</p>
  <input id="inDate" type="date">
  </br>
  <p>Select your Check-out date please</p>
  <input id="outDate" type="date">
  </br>
  <span>You are staying</span><span id="stay"></span> <span> days with us.</span>
  </br>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your JS?

Comment: var date1 = new Date("7/13/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/15/2010");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

Comment: Check my answer....

Answer (score 2):

To get "Check-in date":

```
var inDate=document.getElementById("inDate").value;
```

To get "Check-out date"

```
var outDate=document.getElementById("outDate").value;
```

Comment: Great thanks, and how do I show in my HTML  the dayDiff variable calculated in my JS ?

Comment: document.getElementById("stay")= "your answer";
I suggest you should browse the following website for learning how to use javascript to manipulate the DOM object?
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you want the date picker just import jquery UI library it will allow you insert the date calendar directly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
   <p>Select your Check-in date please</p>
   <input id="inDate" type="date">
   </br>
   <p>Select your Check-out date please</p>
   <input id="outDate" type="date">
   </br>
   <span>You are staying</span><span id="stay"></span> <span> days with us.</span>
</br> 
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Add add this follow javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#inDate, #outDate" ).datepicker();
  });
```

Here is the link to jsbin: https://jsbin.com/kunugi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you very much @tess hsu

Comment: No problem, hope this is help

Answer (score 0):

Read the code comments ,hope this will help

```js
function calc() {
  // get corresponding value from input
  var inDate = document.getElementById('inDate').value;
  var outDate = document.getElementById('outDate').value;

  // allow calculations if both input fields have values, otherwise error can occur while calculating date
  if (inDate && outDate) {


    // convert to date format
    var date1 = new Date(inDate);
    var date2 = new Date(outDate);


    // code for checking date1 > date 2 if you want 
    //calculations 
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

    //for Displaying in html
    document.getElementById('stay').innerHTML = diffDays;

  }

}

// adding event so that when we change any one of the field, the functuion will calculate the daydiff and display in the html page
document.getElementById('outDate').addEventListener("change", calc);
document.getElementById('inDate').addEventListener("change", calc);
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Select your Check-in date please</p>
  <input id="inDate" type="date">

  <p>Select your Check-out date please</p>
  <input id="outDate" type="date">

  <span>You are staying </span><span id="stay"></span> <span> days with us.</span>

</form>
```